# WooCommerce - Where is functions.php?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a very simple question (I hope).  I am trying to edit the number of products displayed on my Shop page in my WooCommerce WordPress site, and all attempts thus far have been unsuccessful.  I have come across some documentation stating that you can put `dd_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 24;' ), 20 );` in the `functions.php` file but I am unable to find the PHP file.

I have searched all through the `root WP` folder, `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce` folder, `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes` folder and `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/` folder through an FTP client and haven't found anything.

Where is it?

Comment: It is found at `/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/functions.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woocommerce is a [plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins). The `functions.php` file is a [Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) component, which is auto-loaded by WordPress Core when the theme boots.

While Woocommerce, or any other plugin, may have a file named `functions.php` but such is not required and it is not the `functions.php` typically referenced here and elsewhere when people suggest adding code that file, and a file of that name used by a plugin won't be auto-loaded by Core but would have to be loaded by plugin code.

There are [Woocommerce themes](http://www.woothemes.com/product-category/themes/woocommerce/), which probably have a `functions.php`, though `functions.php` is not a required theme file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a functions file for Woocommerce. A file like functions4woo.php in your theme folder, because you probably will need to add more functions to WC and will be easier to work things if they're in diferent files. So you would have the Wordpress functions.php and functions4woo.php that would serve Woocommerce.

Doing this you need to add the following to functions.php

```
// WOOCOMMERCE FUNCTIONS
function functions4woo()
{
   // Here we load from our includes directory
   // This considers parent and child themes as well    
 locate_template( array( 'functions4woo.php' ), true, true );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'functions4woo' );
// END WOOCOMMERCE FUNCTIONS
```

I prefer this way so I get things organized.

Good luck to your project.

H.